# Applying Jacobi–Anger expansion with fourier series

Tags: fourier-series, bessel-functions

I am looking at a paper that has the following expression

$$J_\mu = J \exp[i \alpha \sin(\omega t-\phi_\mu)]\exp[-i \omega t]$$
It then says  "parameters whose Fourier series read"
$$J_\mu(t)=\sum_{s=-\infty}^\infty\mathscr{J}_{1+s}(\alpha)e^{-i (1+s)\phi_\mu}e^{is \omega t}$$

I am failing to see where this comes from.
In order to get the bessel functions, do I have to compute the coefficients of the fourier series using orthogonality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [generating function for the Bessel functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.12.E1)
\begin{equation}
 e^{\frac{1}{2}z(t-t^{-1})}=\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}t^{m}J_{m}\left(z\right)
\end{equation} 
with $z=\alpha$ and $t=\exp\left[ i\left( \omega t-\phi_\mu \right) \right]$
one obtains
\begin{equation}
 \exp[i \alpha \sin(\omega t-\phi_\mu)]=\sum_m \exp\left[ im\left( \omega t-\phi_\mu \right) \right]
\end{equation} 
\begin{align}
 J_\mu &= J \exp[i \alpha \sin(\omega t-\phi_\mu)]\exp[-i \omega t]\\
 &=J\sum_m J_m(\alpha)\exp\left[ im\left( \omega t-\phi_\mu \right) \right]e^{-i\omega t}\\
 &=J\sum_mJ_m(\alpha) \exp\left( i(m-1) \omega t \right)e^{-im\phi_\mu}\\
 &=J\sum_sJ_{s+1}(\alpha) e^{-i(s+1)\phi_\mu }e^{is \omega t}
\end{align}
as expected.